# Injectivity of the usual map $C(X)\otimes C(Y)\to C(X\times Y)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact Hausdorff spaces and consider $C(X)$ and $C(Y)$ the spaces of real or complex-valued continuous functiosn on $X$ and $Y$ respectively.

It is "well-known" that $C(X\times Y)$ is isomorphic to a suitable completion of the algebraic tensor product $C(X)\otimes C(Y)$. If $f\in C(X)$ and $g\in C(Y)$, the pure tensor $f\otimes g$ corresponds to the function $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)g(y$).

It is not hard to see that the image of $C(X)\otimes C(Y)$ inside $C(X\times Y)$ is a dense subspace (wrt supremum norm), using partitions of unity or Stone-Weierstrass.

> But how to prove that the inclusion $C(X)\otimes C(Y)\to C(X\times Y)$ is injective?

According to https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.tmj/1178243579, there is a "$\lambda$-norm" on any tensor product of Banach spaces, and in the case at hand the $\lambda$-norm of $C(X)\otimes C(Y)$ is the supremum norm of $C(X\times Y)$. It references a book from 1950 so it is somewhat dated, but anyway seems correct.

However I am more interested in studying spaces of non-scalar valued functions, and Schatten's book relies heavily on the real/complex Banach spaces. So a proof of injectivity without this assumption would be much more interesting.

For example, if $X$ and $Y$ are finite spaces we can prove that the map $C(X)\otimes C(Y)\to C(X\times Y)$ above is an isomorphism quite easily.

More generally, let $R$ be any discrete commutative ring and $X$ and $Y$ two Stone spaces. Let $C(X,R)$ and $C(Y,R)$ be the $R$-algebras of locally constant $R$-valued functions. Then $C(X\times Y,R)$ is isomorphic (as an $R$-algebra) to the (algebraic) tensor product $C(X,R)\otimes_R C(Y,R)$ via the same type of map as above. Another version would be the following:

> What if we consider non-scalar valued functions, is a similar result valid? E.g. let $A$ be a commutative Banach algebra. Is the analogous map $C(X,A)\otimes_A C(Y,A)\to C(X\times Y,A)$ still injective?

Comment: If the $(a_i)_i,(b_j)_j$ are linearly independent so will be $\sum_(a_i(x)b_j(y))_{i,j}$. 
What norm will you consider on $C(X)\otimes C(Y)$.